# Minimum number of vertices whose removal makes the graph no longer connected

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Given a undirected and connected graph G = (V, E). Find the minimum number of verticies whose removal make the graph no longer a connected graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the vertex connectivity problem.

A pseudo-code implementation of the algorithm can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph#Computational_complexity), which you may find helpful.